# PL/SQL nothing is displaying and I enabled DBMS

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am getting a duplicate record error and when I run this code and if I remove the line that declares the variable that is duplicated I then get saying I cannot use that variable in the fetch to output my loop.  Seems like once I get rid of an error another one pops up.  Please give me some direction.  First time posting here.  Be gentle.  Thanks.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE DISP_GUIDE_NAME(I_GUIDE_NUM IN 
GUIDE.GUIDE_NUM%TYPE) AS

I_GUIDE_NUM GUIDE.GUIDE_NUM%TYPE;
I_GUIDE_FNAME GUIDE.FIRST_NAME%TYPE;
I_GUIDE_LNAME GUIDE.LAST_NAME%TYPE;

CURSOR GUIDEGROUP IS
SELECT GUIDE.GUIDE_NUM, GUIDE.FIRST_NAME, GUIDE.LAST_NAME
FROM GUIDE
WHERE GUIDE.GUIDE_NUM = I_GUIDE_NUM;

BEGIN

OPEN GUIDEGROUP;

LOOP
  FETCH GUIDEGROUP INTO I_GUIDE_NUM, I_GUIDE_FNAME, I_GUIDE_LNAME;
  EXIT WHEN GUIDEGROUP%NOTFOUND;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(I_GUIDE_NUM||' '||I_GUIDE_FNAME||' '||I_GUIDE_LNAME);
END LOOP;

CLOSE GUIDEGROUP;
END;
/
```

Comment: What "others" mean? Edit your title.

Comment: So which is the variable that is duplicated that is causing the error?

Comment: The others refers to other errors.  After I remove the declaration of the I_GUIDE_NUM variable, it then says I cannot use it in the fetch.

Comment: The variable I assume they are identifying is I_GUIDE_NUM variable.

Comment: You have two variables with the same name in the same scope. The first `I_GUIDE_NUM` is your input parameter variable. The second is the local variable you are declaring. One of the two needs to be changed. Consider using a different prefix for local variables (such as `l_`) to better differentiate between inputs and local variables.

Answer (score 0):

To address the (current) title "PL/SQL nothing is displaying and I enabled DBMS", and based on the (current) code snippet, after your BEGIN you should enable output.

```
DBMS_OUTPUT.ENABLE([Some Number Of Bytes]);
```

In addition, if running via SQL*PLUS ...

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
```

... prior to executing the script.

Rename your parameter to begin with "P_" and also make that addition to the reference in the WHERE clause in the CURSOR.

```
CREATE TABLE GUIDE
(
 guide_num      NUMBER
,first_name     VARCHAR2(0032)
,last_name      VARCHAR2(0032)
);

INSERT INTO GUIDE VALUES (0001, 'Don',   'Quiote');
INSERT INTO GUIDE VALUES (0002, 'Max',   'Headroom');
INSERT INTO GUIDE VALUES (0042, 'Peter', 'Griffin');
COMMIT;

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE DISP_GUIDE_NAME
    (
     P_I_GUIDE_NUM IN   GUIDE.GUIDE_NUM%TYPE
    )
AS

    I_GUIDE_NUM     GUIDE.GUIDE_NUM%TYPE;
    I_GUIDE_FNAME   GUIDE.FIRST_NAME%TYPE;
    I_GUIDE_LNAME   GUIDE.LAST_NAME%TYPE;

    CURSOR GUIDEGROUP IS
        SELECT
             GUIDE.GUIDE_NUM
            ,GUIDE.FIRST_NAME
            ,GUIDE.LAST_NAME
        FROM GUIDE
        WHERE GUIDE.GUIDE_NUM = P_I_GUIDE_NUM;

BEGIN

OPEN GUIDEGROUP;

LOOP
  FETCH GUIDEGROUP INTO I_GUIDE_NUM, I_GUIDE_FNAME, I_GUIDE_LNAME;
  EXIT WHEN GUIDEGROUP%NOTFOUND;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(I_GUIDE_NUM||' '||I_GUIDE_FNAME||' '||I_GUIDE_LNAME);
END LOOP;

CLOSE GUIDEGROUP;
END;
/

BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.ENABLE(1000);
    Disp_Guide_Name(0042);
END;
/

DROP TABLE GUIDE;
```